# My keystore password for releasing my app is correct but it is being rejected

Tags: android, android-studio, android-keystore

After updating my Android Studio to 3.3.1 version, it is now rejecting my keystore password and I am 100% sure that my password is correct,

I have searched about solutions of that but I didn't get suitable solution
One of the solution I have tried is to run a certain command on my command prompt which is

```
keytool -list -v -keystore C:\....\keystore.jks -storepass HereMyPassword -alias HereMyAlias
```

but I end up getting details of my keystore.

Comment: How did you use the keystore, is it inside your build.gradle or via path file?

Comment: Are you using the same keystore file?